# Express route function not showing text

Tags: express

app.js :

```
var index = require('./routes/index2');
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
```

index2.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

when I go to localhost:3000/ I don't see the text in send function

Answer (score 0):

I guess your browser is you waiting for a response?

If you change index2.js to be a function and return the router, you'll be adding it as a middleware with app.use('url', middleware). I hope this helps

**app.js**

```
var index = require('./routes/index2');
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/', index()); //Invoke the object to get the router back
app.use('/users', users);
```

**index2.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function() {

  /* GET users listing. */
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('respond with a resource');
  });

  return router;
};
```

Returning the router from index2 to be used as a middleware

Comment: in other words, you need use `module.exports` somewhere in **index2.js**. :)